# Use customized lint check on the fly in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, lint

I want to write a lint check which can detect issues in resource file on the fly. For example, I want my Android Studio to highlight my `<TextView>` and give warning when it does not have `android:padding`.

I read [this](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules) and found that we can write custom lint but only can we use it through command line but not on the fly. I also found that there is plugin like SonarLint which provides on-the-fly custom lint check.

So my question is:

Is it true that creating an Android Studio plugin is the only way to make custom lint check work on the fly?

Comment: It seems that the lint API will change soon: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=224584

Answer (score 1):

I do not accurately answer your question because I don't have own custom lint checks. However, I'm using **rxLint** library which is not part of Android build tools and **Android Studio** highlights issues in code that are reported.

So if you will make your custom lint checks as a separate module and put your main project depend on it then **Android Studio** will highlight it.